# Escape jq query and save output in a bash variable

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to save the output of the following command in a bash variable in a script. But no matter how hard i try, i am unable to escape the quotes correctly.

Here is the command whose output i want to save in a variable.

```
$ echo '[{"field":"fieldA","bucket":["a","b","c"]},{"field":"fieldB","bucket":["a","b","c","d"]}]' | jq -r '.[]|{field, bucketText: .bucket|join(", ")}|join(" found in bucket: ")'
fieldA found in bucket: a, b, c
fieldB found in bucket: a, b, c, d
```

And here is my attempt in my script file

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='[{"field":"fieldA","bucket":["a","b","c"]},{"field":"fieldB","bucket":["a","b","c","d"]}]'

OUTPUT_LINES="$(echo ${INPUT} | jq -r '.[]|{field, bucketText: .bucket|join(\", \")}|join(\" found in bucket: \")')"

printf "%s\n" "${OUTPUT_LINES}"
```

Comment: Only potentially-syntactic quotes require escaping. Anything that's coming from a command substitution or expansion is literal, not syntactic, unless something is explicitly done to change that. [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discusses a different common mistake that stems from the same misunderstanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do escaped double quotes in command substitution become literals in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337329/in-bash-escaped-double-quote-from-command-substitution-become-permanent-literals)

Comment: See also [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser), noting that step 5 (replacing variables with expansion results) happens *after* step 2 (parsing quotes), and so expansion results can't possibly change how content is parsed for quoting purposes -- because the syntactic parsing *already finished* before expansions (like replacing `$(...something...)` with `...something...`'s output) take place, with only string-splitting and globbing (which are suppressed by putting that expansion in double quotes, or by it being on the right-hand side of an assignment) still pending.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input='[{"field":"fieldA","bucket":["a","b","c"]},{"field":"fieldB","bucket":["a","b","c","d"]}]'

output="$(jq -r '.[]|{field, bucketText: .bucket|join(", ")}|join(" found in bucket: ")' <<< "$input")"

printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

**Output:**

```
fieldA found in bucket: a, b, c
fieldB found in bucket: a, b, c, d
```

**Suggested changes:**

- No need to escape double quote inside single quoted `jq` commands
- Recommended to use lowercase variables instead of all uppercase
- Avoid pipeline and use here-string in `jq` command to avoid unnecessary sub-shell creation

Comment: In other words, the reason why OP is unable to escape it correctly is that it doesn't require any escaping.